# Flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

When i open a certain project, i need to get some dependencies, but when i click for the option, the terminal shows me this:

```
C:\dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Resolving dependencies...
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety.

The current Dart SDK (3.2.6) only supports null safety.

For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
Process finished with exit code 65
```

What's wrong? The pubspec.yaml file looks like this:

```
name: mi_card
description: A new Flutter application.


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter



flutter:

 
  uses-material-design: true
```

Chat gpt tells me the environmetent should be
environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

Which i already have. Dont realy undesrtand whats the problem

Comment: You will definitely need to migrate that to null safety, but if you've already installed the latest flutter, you are missing some tools to do that.  See my video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olqmK-opexA for instructions on how to have multiple flutter installs, including one that is old enough to do null-safety mmigration.

Comment: I would suggest update your flutter tools, create a new flutter project, migrate your code to this newly created project

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is just the useless repetition of the tag information and the word *project*, which says nothing. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that its content is clear to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results. For suggestions about writing a good title, see [ask]. You'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.